# Trace of $2n$ gamma matrices

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, trace

To proof
$$\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2n}})
=\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_{2n}}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_1}),$$

I use $\gamma_\mu^\dagger=\gamma^0\gamma_\mu\gamma^0$ and get

$$\cdots=\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma^0\gamma_{\mu_1}^\dagger\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2n}}^\dagger\gamma^0)
=\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}^\dagger\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2n}}^\dagger)
=\mathrm{Tr}[(\gamma_{\mu_{2n}}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_1})^\dagger].$$

The final step is to remove the conjugate transpose. In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Identities), it says that *the trace of a product of gamma matrices is real*. How can I proof it?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1):

Now I have found a proof for $\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2n}})\in\mathbb{R}$ with mathematical induction:

1. For $n=1$. We know that $\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_\mu\gamma_\nu)=4\eta_{\mu\nu}\in\mathbb{R}$.
2. Assume the conclusion is correct for $n=k$, i.e.

$$\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2k}})\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Then for $n=k+1$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2k}}
            \gamma_{\mu_{2k+1}}\gamma_{\mu_{2k+2}})
&=\mathrm{Tr}[\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2k}}
 (2\eta_{\mu_{2k+1},\,\mu_{2k+2}} - \gamma_{\mu_{2k+2}}\gamma_{\mu_{2k+1}})] \\
&=2\eta_{\mu_{2k+1},\,\mu_{2k+2}} \mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots
                                              \gamma_{\mu_{2k}})
 -\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2k}} 
              \gamma_{\mu_{2k+2}}\gamma_{\mu_{2k+1}}).
\end{align}
$$

Note that the first term is real, and the second term can be expanded in the same way:

$$
\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2k}}
            \gamma_{\mu_{2k+2}}\gamma_{\mu_{2k+1}})
=2\eta_{\mu_{2k},\,\mu_{2k+2}}\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2k-1}}
                                          \gamma_{\mu_{2k+1}})
 -\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2k-1}} 
              \gamma_{\mu_{2k+2}}\gamma_{\mu_{2k}}\gamma_{\mu_{2k+1}}).
$$

The first term has $2n$ gamma matrices and hence is real as well.
Do the same process $2n+1$ times, we can move $\gamma_{\mu_{2k+2}}$ to the first position. Each movement will lead to a minus sign, so we have

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2k}}
            \gamma_{\mu_{2k+1}}\gamma_{\mu_{2k+2}})
&=S+(-1)^{2n+1}\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_{2k+2}}\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots
                           \gamma_{\mu_{2k}}\gamma_{\mu_{2k+1}})\\
&=S-\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_{2k+2}}\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots
                \gamma_{\mu_{2k}}\gamma_{\mu_{2k+1}})\\
&=S-\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2k}}
                \gamma_{\mu_{2k+1}}\gamma_{\mu_{2k+2}})
  \tag*{$\mathrm{Tr}(AB)=\mathrm{Tr}(BA)$},
\end{align}
$$

where $S$ contains only $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ and trace of $2n$ gamma matrices, so $S\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now obviously we have

$$
\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2k+2}})
=\frac{S}{2}\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Given the above, we now reach the conclusion that

$$
\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu_1}\cdots\gamma_{\mu_{2n}})\in\mathbb{R}
$$

for any $n$.